# about subplot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am reading about machine learn algorithms using python. Though I am new to python I am trying to follow most of the stuff. But I am finding difficult to understand below

```
 axprops = dict(xticks=[], yticks=[])
 createPlot.ax1 = plt.subplot(111, frameon=False, **axprops)
```

In above code what **axprops mean here? and why we are appending ** before axprops?

What is xticks and yticks in this context?

What is the declaration of subplot. I am not able to find one when I searched in Internet.

Thanks

Comment: The whole kwargs(`**`) thing is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/1072229

Comment: [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google knows nothing about axprops, it's an arbitraty variable name - search for `*args` and `**kwargs` (the latter meaning, "keyword arguments") in the python tutorial, or on SO as stated in the comment.

You can pass a lot of keyword arguments to your function in one call by providing a dictionary (in which the keys are limited to parameters the funtion expects, of course, but need not contain all parameters). In your example it's completely useless (well, a question of style), but you could construct this dictionary dynamically inside `if`s, for example...

In this case you pass those arguments to tell the subplot not to draw any ticks (just try without passing the `axprops`, and you will see what this changes, it will autogenerate ticks which it thinks appropriate for the data)